# nginx redirect location that not have prefix

Tags: nginx

When the server receive the requests have following characteristics:

1. URI does NOT has prefix "/api/index.php"
2. request port is 80

Then these requests should be redirect to HTTPS.

So I config the nginx like this:

```
location !~ ^/api/index.php/ {
    if ($server_port = "80") {
            return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}
```

But when I restart the nginx, got fllowing error message:

```
[emerg] invalid location modifier "!~"
```

It confused me that "!~" should be the legal modifier, what does this message mean? And how could I solved it?

Comment: The [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) lists four modifiers and `!~` is not one of them.

Comment: Oh, maybe I read the wrong version

Comment: The `!~` is one of the operators used with `if`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if)